# Edit, Add, Delete records with MySQLi from browser to database on server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I modified this tutoriel, https://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/ , to print 5 main column: ID, First name, Last name, Position, & Shirt # plus 2 other columns for edit and delete buttons. After editing the code, The table is up but when I am editing or recording a new entry, my new entries do not get saved into my database. Here is the code, please have a look and help me find what is wrong. The code was not properly formatted so I put it on github here https://github.com/godgive/CS50/blob/master/records.php and tried to make it readable.

Edit:

Why when trying to edit or add new records through the browser, the data do not get saved into the MySQL database to be displayed after a refresh?

```
<?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/
// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");
// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($first = '', $last ='', $pos = '', $shirt = '', $error = '', $id = '')
{ ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
        </title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      </head>
          <body>
             <h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
             <?php if ($error != '') {
              echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
              . "</div>";
 } ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($id != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<?php 

} ?>

<strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="firstname"
value="<?php echo $first; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Last Name:   *</strong> <input type="text" name="lastname"
value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Position: </strong> <input type="text" name="position"
value="<?php echo $pos; ?>"/><br/r>

<strong>Shirt #:  </strong> <input type="number" name="shirt"
value="<?php echo $shirt; ?>"/>
<p>* required</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }
/*
EDIT RECORD
*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
    // get variables from the URL/form
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $position = htmlentities($_POST['position'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $shirt = htmlentities($_POST['shirt'], ENT_QUOTES);
// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
{
    // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
    renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $pos, $shirt, $error, $id);
}
else
{
    // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?,
    position = ?, shirt = ?
    WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
// redirect the user once the form is updated
    header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
        echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
      // make sure the 'id' value is valid
      if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{ 
      // get 'id' from URL
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      // get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=?"))
{
          $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt);
          $stmt->fetch();
                // show the form
        renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt, NULL, $id);
        $stmt->close();
}
            // show an error if the query has an error
else
{
          echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
          // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else
{
          header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}
/*
NEW RECORD
*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
          // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
          // get the form data
        $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $position = htmlentities($_POST['position'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $shirt = htmlentities($_POST['shirt'], ENT_QUOTES);
// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
{
        // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
        renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $pos, $shirt, $error);
}
else
{
        // insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT players (firstname, lastname, position, shirt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
// redirec the user
        header("Location: view.php");
}
}
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
        renderForm();
}
}
// close the mysqli connection
          $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You should add the source code to the question, not behind a link which gets deleted some day. You also haven't asked a question, which you should do. Also please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question on why you shouldn't ask something generic like "help me, what's wrong", this is way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code closely again, I changed

```
else
{
              // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?,
    position = ?, shirt = ?
    WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt, $id);
```

into

```
else
{
          // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?,
    position = ?, shirt = ?
    WHERE id=?"))
{
            /// added two more s here
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt, $id);
```

then

```
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT players (firstname, lastname, position, shirt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

into

```
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT players (firstname, lastname, position, shirt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
                            /// here, with the place holders 's'
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $position, $shirt);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

Now it is working as expected.
This is my first time working with php and MySQL so correct me if those 's' should not be referred to as placeholders.